# Beginner question on Facebook application

Tags: facebook

I am new to facebook application development.My question is:do I have to have a server to make the development?Could I do it on my own local machine and try it out?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep, you can use your own local machine; nothing's limiting you to do that.

well, it actually depends on the kind of application you are building, if its more of data-analysis or merely tinkering; working on a localmachine makes perfect sense.

but if your intention is to get bunch of other users; yeah go to hosting on an external server.